# How to change cout string for object

Tags: c++, c++11

here is my code

```
class MyObj {
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::cout << new MyObj();
};
```

the output is `0x613c40`, is there way to change `0x613c40` to 'my object description', I know java has `toString`

Comment: The output is an address because you're printing a pointer. You can't change a pointer to be output as something it's not.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
class MyObj {
  public:
    int member_;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyObj& myObj)
{
    return os << "MyObj{ member_ " << myObj.member_ << " }";
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    MyObj myObj { 42 };
    std::cout << myObj << '\n';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use typeid operator.
MyObj obj;
std::cout << "MyObj has type: " << typeid(obj).name() << '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to overload the "<<" operator to be used with an object of type "MyObj"

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& output, const MyObj& myObj)
{    
   return output << "Whatever you want to output";
}
```

The whatever you want to output could be a name it has of the public member or private it contains , up to you at this point.